# How would I Insert a fileupload selection into a gridview, then add new row?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I would like to have a gridview that has a fileupload control with a button labeled "Add", like so:

```
 Filename                            |  Delete
 ---------------------------------------------
 [FileUpload Control][Add button]    |    X
```

When a user presses the Add button, they will browse for a file to upload and select it.  When the selection is complete, a new grid row is generated in order to give the user an option to select more files.

```
Filename                            |  Delete
---------------------------------------------
Filename in text box                |    X       <- fileupload control is replaced w/txtbox containing filename selected
[FileUpload Control][Add button]    |            <- new row is added for user to select another file
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: I can make a gridview. I can throw a fileupload control in it no problem. I can add a row.  I guess I'm just confused about how to remove a control and replace it with another.  And is a gridview even the right choice of control to hold these values.. I mean i'm not even using any databinding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis of this would be to add a new template field column to your GridView and add your button control into this template. From here you would then have to add all of the functionality of what the button controls in your code behind where you would handle the file upload and you would run an insert query probably to add the new row then refresh your grid.

It is hard to tell the exact specifications that you are asking for but if you are wanting only one button at the very bottom of the gridview look into adding it into the footer template of the gridview (click the little arrow at the side of the gridview, then choose edit templates, select footer, add control here), which should add this control to the very bottom of your gridview. What I explained in the first paragraph will add the control to every row.